# decrypt pfx OR p12 using iaik_full_signed.jar in Java fails

Tags: java, security, pfx, pkcs#12

I am writing a code to decrypt a .pfx or .p12 certificate using above mentioned library.
It simply takes password into charArray. But it can not decrypt it. It generates the following exception.

```
iaik.pkcs.PKCSException: Unable to decrypt PrivateKey! java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Unable to decrypt private key: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at iaik.pkcs.pkcs12.AuthenticatedSafe.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at iaik.pkcs.pkcs12.PKCS12.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at com.code.others.SecurityCerts.main(SecurityCerts.java:50)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've also checked that Certificates are valid or not using java keytool from command prompt. But they are valid.

Comment: Another thing, I've also tried to replaced JCE with its unlimited version. In which I've replaced my local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar files.